# VBA runtime error 13 using Msgbox

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, msgbox

I'm very new to VBA and only have a basic level of knowledge.

I have been trying to create a macro to cross-reference data on one sheet against multiple other sheets within the same work book.  If a record is found I would like a msgbox to appear to alert the user of the location of the data.

After many hours searching the internet and piecing together bits of code this is what I have

```
Sub search()
Dim ws As Worksheet, found As Range
Dim TextToFind(1 To 20) As String
Dim iText As Long

TextToFind(1) = "Jade Smith"
TextToFind(2) = "Bob Collins"
TextToFind(3) = "Jemima Smythe"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Name <> "Blacklisted Candidates" Then 'Do not search blacklist candidates!
            iText = 1
            Do While iText <= UBound(TextToFind)
                If TextToFind(iText) <> "" Then 'Do not search blank strings!
                    Set found = .UsedRange.Find(what:=TextToFind(iText), LookIn:=xlformulas, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

                    If Not found Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & found.Address
                    Else
                        MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
                    End If
                    iText = iText + 1
                End If
            Loop
        End If
   End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

This code however doesn't find the values from other sheets.

when testing this I just get the msgbox when no data has been found even though there is test data there.

I have a workbook of approx 9 sheets (ever growing) and I want to search the first 9 columns of each work book for the specified data which as you can see I have manually input into the macro but when running the macro I get no results returned even though there is data to find.

Comment: why do you have the "*" at the end ?

Comment: modify `*MsgBox ("Proxy Candidate Found at " And rngX.Address)` to `MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & rngX.Address`

Comment: Did you omit some code?  @litelite has the correct answer re. the Error 13, but your `Do` loop doesn't have any way to *exit*. Also `If Rng Is found Then` should be `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: @Comintern There is a `goto` in the if which he uses to break out of the infinite loop

Comment: @Comintern true, i read that quickly. His code will never end...

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use the binary operator `And` on two strings. You probably meant to use `&` instead to concatenate strings.

Documentation :

- [`And`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [`&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk(v=vs.90).aspx)

(The docs are for VB.Net, but they work the same in both languages)

So to fix it, replace

```
MsgBox ("Proxy Candidate Found at " And rngX.Address)
```

By

```
MsgBox ("Proxy Candidate Found at " & rngX.Address)
```

Comment: The parentheses are superfluous. And they can bite you in the rear end, too - see [this is confusing, why not just always use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201609061647521040081).

Comment: Office VBA documentation for `&` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/gg264104.aspx) and for `And` it's [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/gg251591.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to account for searching in cell whose content derives from a formula

to both summarize all what has been already pointed out in comments and litelite answer and add some 0.02 cents, here a working code

```
Option Explicit

Sub search()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, found As Range
    Dim TextToFind(1 To 20) As String
    Dim iText As Long

    TextToFind(1) = "xxxx"
    TextToFind(2) = "xxxx"
    TextToFind(3) = "xxxxx"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .name <> "Blacklisted Candidates" Then 'Do not search blacklist candidates!
                iText = 1
                Do While iText <= UBound(TextToFind)
                    If TextToFind(iText) <> "" Then 'Do not search blank strings!
                        Set found = .UsedRange.Find(what:=TextToFind(iText), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

                        If Not found Is Nothing Then
                            MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & found.Address
                        Else
                            MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
                        End If
                        iText = iText + 1
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
       End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I now no longer get the error message. however I have tested this after inserting a text string manually that I am searching for.  although it doesn't actually find  the text string. can any of you help?

Comment: more info needed: update your question with examples of minimal set of data reproducing the issue. moreover specify if cells to be searched for hold _constant_ values or _formulas_ results

Comment: I have updated the question now if anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated! thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I saw in you edited question that cells to be searched in host a concatenation formula. therefore see edited answer where I just substituted `xlValues` with `xlFormulas`.

Comment: @Lbrin, did you get through it?

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why it isn't working, I have updated it as you have suggested but still nothing :/

Comment: what does _still nothing_ mean? update your question with examples of minimal set of data reproducing the issue.